# Many paralllel transactions vs transaction isolation level in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, concurrency, transactions, ejb, eclipselink

My app retrieves requests using Weblogic Server, EJB, EclipseLink as a ORM. 
The business logic looks as follows. 
Select all records from table A where A.col = 'ABC' (ABS is a value from request)
If none of them satisfy some condition, create new one.

Now suppose that 10 parallel requests have been sent with the same payload.
I have a default isolation level in my Oracle DB (READ_COMMITED). In this case, many transactions are performed in parallel:

```
Req1 start T1    
Req2 start T2   
T1 select rows  
T2 select rows  
T1 insert new one (no rows with col = 'ABC')
T1 COMMIT
T2 insert new one (no rows with col = 'ABC')
T2 COMMIT
```

As a result, 1-10 rows are created instead of 1.

Oracle doesn't have REPEATABLE_READS isolation level. SERIALIZABLE has a negative impact to throughput.

Comment: And where is your question ?

Comment: I think your app logic is wrong somewhere, if you need put in parallel add additional verification go with serialization, did you read this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/consist.htm. Or maybe use queues if you need to be very fast.

Comment: Serializable is what you would need since you want to prevent other threads from inserting after you execute your read query. Otherwise, use a constraint on the column, and catch the exception. If your app gets an exception, re-read the row since it means another thread has entered it and it now exists, and continue your logic from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock mode is the solution.
PESSIMISTIC_WRITE acquire exclusive lock on selected row using FOR UPDATE (Oracle). [JPA](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-javax.persistence.LockModeType-) takes LockModeType as a one of method argument, e.g. in *find* method.
Of course, consistency at the expense of throughput.